# "This account is not allowed to use WhatsApp due to spam" after registering with a new SIM card

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sim-card

I have recently upgraded my mobile to Samsung Galaxy S24 Ultra. I kept my old S21 Ultra, with the idea to use that for personal things and my new S24 Ultra for business.

I had WhatsApp Business, installed on my old mobile, linked to my old mobile number. I have since ordered a new SIM card, which I wanted to put in my old phone, to create a work-free SIM/number to use for personal, away from my work.

I factory reset my S21 Ultra, and when trying to register WhatsApp, it allows me through. As soon as I send one message, it immediately blocks the phone, saying "This account is not allowed to use WhatsApp due to spam" (chats are still on this device).

Despite factory reset, how do I permanently delete my old chats from old SIM/number so I can use WhatsApp on new SIM/number as hoped?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that new mobile number you have been assigned was previously assigned to someone whose account was blocked by Whatsapp.  And Whatsapp is linked to your mobile number.

It is quite common for providers to recycle the numbers (especially for landlines).

Try the new SIM on your S24, if it still has the same behaviour then you will need to obtain a different mobile number.

If you are unable to remove the chats on the old phone, put the old SIM in the old phone and remove the chats.  Note, they will then be gone permanently.  They are linked to your old SIM (number).  You will not be able to access them on te new phone either.